# XPath expression to return an array of node names and their text content

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shop>
    <order>
        <name>Mr A Beasy</name>
        <date>12/03/2017</date>
        <payment>Debit Card</payment>
    </order>
    <order>
        <name>Mrs D Ehffi</name>
        <date>13/04/2017</date>
        <payment>Paypal</payment>
    </order>
</shop>
```

Using the above xml as an example, I am trying to retrieve each 'order' along with the node names and text contents contained in it. I want to eventually save each `name`, `date` and `payment`'s text content to a corresponding field in a java object.

The problem is, the `name`, `date` and `payment` nodes are not always guaranteed to be there. So I need a way to first check if the `name` node exists and is not null, then extract its text content and save that to my java object.

I have tried:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate("/shop/order", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
String name = nodeList.item(i).getNodeName();
String text = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
```

I hoped this would give me a nice array with two 'order' nodesets that I could iterate through and get the values of the nodes and their contents, but it doesn't work. For some reason my `nodeList` has a bunch of `\n` in it.

I am unsure of how to search my `nodeList` for a specific node called name, and if it exists extract its value. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I hoped this would give me a nice array with two 'order' nodesets that
>   I could iterate through and get the values of the nodes and their
>   contents, but it doesn't work. For some reason my nodeList has a bunch
>   of \n in it.

In the example XML you provided, the `<order>` elements contain different types of children.  There are element nodes for `<name>`, `<date>`, and `<payment>` elements, but there are also *text nodes* containing a combination of spaces and newlines.  The text content of each node is comprised of a concatenation of the text node children (only) of that node and all its descendants, in document order.

The XPath expression `/shop/order` evaluates to a node set containing two `Node` objects, each representing one such `<order>` node.  That may well serve your purpose, but invoking `getTextContent()` on those nodes does not, because the result does not contain information about which text comes from which element.

You could get what you want -- the names and content of each `<order>`'s element children -- in at least two ways:

- by evaluating additional XPath expressions with the `<order>` nodes as context, or
- by using DOM methods to walk the subtree rooted at each `<order>`.

The XPath approach is a bit heavier weight, but it is expressible much more compactly, and it deals naturally with child elements being missing or in different orders.  I'm not sure I would have chosen XPath in the first place for data having such simple form, but since you have done so, you might as well continue with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, John. Your first option sounds promising, evaluting additional expressions using the <order> node as context. Could you tell me more about how to do that?

Comment: @DraegerMTN, it's just a variation on what you're already doing.  For example, something like `Node orderNode = nodeList.item(0); name = (String) path.evaluate("name", orderNode, XPathConstants.STRING);`.  The second argument defines the context against which the expression is evaluated.